# What does local _, x = ... do in lua?

Tags: lua

I'm looking at some lua code on github which consists of many folders and files. Next to external libraries, each file starts with:

```
local _,x = ...
```

Now my question is, what is the purpose of this, namely the 3 dots? is it a way to 'import' the global values of x? In what way is it best used?

Comment: "The variable consisting of only an underscore "_" is commonly used as a placeholder when you want to ignore the variable: "
http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy Yeah i figured that. But what do the 3 dots do?

Answer (score 4):

`...` is the variable arguments to the current function.

E.g.:

```
function test(x, y, ...)
    print("x is",x)
    print("y is",y)
    print("... is", ...)

    local a,b,c,d = ...
    print("b is",b)
    print("c is",c)
end
test(1,2,"oat","meal")
```

prints:

```
x is 1
y is 2
... is oat meal
b is meal
c is nil
```

---

Files are also treated as functions. In Lua, when you, or someone else, loads a file (with `load` or `loadfile` or whatever), it returns a function, and then to run the code, you call the function. And when you call the function, you can pass arguments. And none of the arguments have names, but the file can read them with `...`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Could you maybe extend the clarification on how the local x = ... would be used between files? I understand now how this works in a function when the function arg has ... but how does it work between two lua files?

Comment: @Larimar Files are functions

Comment: So if i would make a table that contains functions in one file. I could essentially import that table(and those functions) in another file when using local x = ...? If so, how? If simple require() is better to use when you need functions of another file, then in which situations do you use the ...? Apologies for the extended questioning beyond the main question, having a hard time trying to wrap my head around it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Larimar When you use `require` it does not pass any arguments to the file. If you want to load a file and then call it, by yourself without using the `require` system, then you can pass arguments.

Comment: @Larimar Try finding out how to run another file "manually" without `require` or `dofile`. You will see where the arguments go

Answer (score 2):

They are arguments from the command line.

Read lua's reference manual, in the chapter [**Lua Standalone**](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#7), it says:

> ...If there is a script, the script is called with arguments arg[1], ···, arg[#arg]. Like all chunks in Lua, the script is compiled as **a vararg function**.

For example if your lua script is run with the command line:

```
lua my_script.lua 10 20
```

In **my_script.lua** you have:

```
local _, x = ...
```

Then `_ = "10"` and `x = "20"`

---

**Update** when a library script is required by another script, the meaning of the 3 dots changes, they are arguments passed from the [`require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-require) function to the searcher:

> Once a loader is found, require calls the loader with two arguments: modname and an extra value, a loader data, also returned by the searcher.

And under `package.searchers`:

> All searchers except the first one (preload) return as the extra value the file name where the module was found

For example if you have a lua file that requires **my_script.lua**.

```
require('my_script')
```

At this time `_ = "my_script"` and `x = "/full/path/to/my_script.lua"`

Note that in lua 5.1, `require` passes only 1 argument to the loader, so `x` is nil.